# Umbrella Exception during fire event in GWT

Tags: exception, gwt

I have a Singleton Instance and when I am Firing the event whose handler uses Singleton instance it resulting in Umbrella Exception.
The code Snippets are

```
@UiHandler("panelButton")
    void handleClick(ClickEvent e) {

         AppUtils.eventBus.addHandler(PanelClickEvent.TYPE, new PanelClickEventHandler());
         AppUtils.eventBus.fireEvent(new PanelClickEvent());

    }
```

The Handler is

```
public class PanelClickEventHandler implements EventHandler{
    @Inject
    PanelDataHandler pdh;
    public void displayPanelGrid() {

        System.out.print(pdh.getPanelList().size());

    }

}
```

The error is with the lines

```
@Inject
PanelDataHandler pdh;
```

My PanelDataHandler is

```
@Singleton
public class PanelDataHandler {
    .......
    @Inject
    public PanelDataHandler(){
        ....
    }
.......
}
```

Is there anything which I am missing?
shouln't I use @singleton object in my handler ?

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace ? There must be something firing the UmbrellaException.

Answer (score 0):

`PanelClickEventHandler` won't be injected if you create it with `new PanelClickEventHandler`. It'll only be if GIN (or whatever you use for dependency injection) creates the instance, or if you explicitly inject its members afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it worked with inject, as I am new to GWT there may be many simple things I am missing, thanks for your help